# nodejs Running something on only a single process pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2, forever

I'm using pm2 to start multiple processes of my server `pm2 start server.js -i max`. There's something I want to run only on a single process though and not all of them. AFAIK pm2 does not have a concept of a master process. I don't see any markers under `process`. I also would prefer not to have a config that fixes the number of processes I have instead of letting it be based on CPU cores.

Comment: I find the last sentence confusing so im not sure if you are ruling it out but have you looked at clustering? Master process with slaves sounds like what you need https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html Create the cluster then use forever or pm2

Comment: @Dennington-bear do I need to? Yes I can run cluster on my own but I'd prefer to just use pm2 or forever since it handles the workers but simpler.

Comment: @Dennington-bear I updated the question with an example config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone let me know if this is correct: I can check if `process.ppid === process.pid`. The other processes are started from one process and we can let that process act as the master.